# React.js how to make a correct callback prop function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

Im working with a react.js app, and I remember that I was able to pass a callback function from a child to a parent with pops, the thing is I cant achieve to do this again (I'd like to keep it simple, without Flux libraries):

So my parent `App`:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }

 showViewAction(viewToShow){
   console.log(viewToShow);
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppMenu showView={this.showViewAction}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my child `AppMenu`:

```
class AppMenu extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }

  showCirculares(){
    this.props.showView("circulares");
  }

  render(){

    return(
    <div>
      <MenuButton onClick={this.showCirculares} buttonTitle="SomeOtherProp"/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Everything I try, I always get:

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined at showCirculares;

I know this will be resolved with a simple task, and that this is basic React.js stuff, its just that I cant find a solution for this!! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `MenuButton`? Is that a button component you got from a library or did you make it yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to bind the `this` context to your callback functions. Do so in the constructor function like so:

App

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.showViewAction = this.showViewAction.bind(this);
 }

 showViewAction(viewToShow){
   console.log(viewToShow);
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppMenu showView={this.showViewAction}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

AppMenu

```
class AppMenu extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.showCirculares = this.showCirculares.bind(this);
 }

  showCirculares(){
    this.props.showView("circulares");
  }

  render(){

    return(
    <div>
      <MenuButton onClick={this.showCirculares} buttonTitle="SomeOtherProp"/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why? The short version is that unless you bind `this`, when your functions run the value of `this` is undefined. What you want is the context of the component instead, so you have to manually bind the functions to it.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. `bind` is only necessary if you need to retain the parent's context. In this case, it's a simple `console.log`

Comment: @Andrew for `showViewAction` you are correct, however I still believe it would be good practice to `bind` it since rarely are such functions completely static and separate from the component context. `showCirculares` absolutely needs to be bound since it's calling `this.props`.

Comment: I agree 100% with your statement and it was something I was considering commenting on. But I think the problem he/she is having is much deeper than a simple `bind` that everyone is assuming.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand better bind and arrow function callbacks.

Comment: @KarloA.López Your issue was resolved with `bind`?

Comment: Yep, both `bind` and use arrow functions worked perfectly!

Comment: It must have been a problem with your `MenuButton` then. `App` wouldn't need the binding. But still good practice to have.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the `showCirculares` with the class so that it does not have `this` undefined. Following are the ways to do this.

Bind your method in constructor like this

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.showCirculares = this.showCirculares.bind(this)
 }

  showCirculares(){
    this.props.showView("circulares");
  }
```

Or simply use arrow function like this

```
showCirculares = () => {
   this.props.showView("circulares");
}
```

Comment: *"Or simply use arrow function like this"* It's not just about using an arrow function. The class field syntax (`foo = bar;`) is currently a proposal, it's not officially part of JavaScript yet.

Comment: @FelixKling I am assuming that OP is using babel transpiler. Wouldn't babel take care of this?

Comment: If it is configured correctly, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind explicitly `showCirculares` using the `bind` function like @jered said, or you can use arrow functions, that are implicitly bound to the calling this.

```
<MenuButton onClick={() => this.showCirculares()} buttonTitle="SomeOtherProp"/>
```